# Sqlite3: Join 3 tables summing rows and checking if a value is not in the row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a question regarding an Sqlite3 query.
The task is only one sentence: Select all customers columns which bought more than 4 times (>=5 times)
between 2018-01-01 and 2018-12-31  and did not buy product number 4402

Explanation about all the database tables for this question:

1) Customer
columns: **CustomerNum**, CustomerName, DateOfBirth, Gender, CustomerAddress, CustomerPhoneNum.

2) Purchase
columns: **PurchaseNum**, PurchaseTime, **CustomerNum**, ShippingCompanyNum

3) PurchaseContains
columns: **PurchaseNum**, SupplierNum, **ProductNum**, Amount

I've bolded the columns I think are necessary to solve this question.

My query is:

```
SELECT Customer.* FROM Customer INNER JOIN Purchase
on Customer.CustomerNum = Purchase.CustomerNum
INNER JOIN PurchaseContains 
on Purchase.PurchaseNum = PurchaseContains.PurchaseNum

WHERE Purchase.PurchaseTime BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31' AND PurchaseContains.ProductNum != 4402

GROUP BY Purchase.CustomerNum
HAVING COUNT(Purchase.PurchaseNum) > 4;
```

However because of the INNER JOIN, I think some of the rows are being duplicated!
For example this is without the inner join of 'PurchaseContains' :

```
SELECT Customer.* FROM Customer INNER JOIN Purchase
on Customer.CustomerNum = Purchase.CustomerNum

--COMMENT:
--INNER JOIN PurchaseContains 
--on Purchase.PurchaseNum = PurchaseContains.PurchaseNum

WHERE Purchase.PurchaseTime BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31' -- COMMENT: AND PurchaseContains.ProductNum != 4402

GROUP BY Purchase.CustomerNum
HAVING COUNT(Purchase.PurchaseNum) > 4;
```

And this returns only 2 rows. But now it does not check if the person did not have a purchase that contains item number 4402 (It should output only 1 person).

The first SQL Query in this question returns **2078** rows!
I'm lost!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in your diagnosis of the problem.  You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Customer c INNER JOIN
     Purchase p
     ON c.CustomerNum = p.CustomerNum
WHERE p.PurchaseTime BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM PurchaseContains pc
                  WHERE pc.PurchaseNum = p.PurchaseNum AND
                        pc.ProductNum = 4402
                 )
GROUP BY p.CustomerNum
HAVING COUNT(p.PurchaseNum) > 4;
```